# PANDAS - How do you concatenate date and text(string) to a new column?

Tags: excel, pandas

i'm fairly new to pandas, i downloaded an excel file which contains public law enforcement data, i wanted to concatenate a date (M/D/Y) column with another column that only has texts and add them in a new column. the columns that i want to concatenate is called 'Primary Offense Description' & the other column is called 'Occurred Date'.

Feel free to ask for the excel file & i shall upload it.

Comment: Seems like your date will also be a string, so just `+`: `df[''Primary Offense Description'] + df['Occurred Date']`

Comment: i have tried it before but it gave me this error, TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<U14') and dtype('<M8[ns]') i'm not really sure what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example dataset,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
"Date" : ['2013-11-24', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24'],
"Fruit" : ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Celery'], 
"Num" : [22.1, 8.6, 7.6, 10.2],
"Color" : ['Yellow', 'Orange', 'Green', 'Green']
})
```

the following line of code will create for you new column named "Combination" in the dataset which combine column Date & Color : 
`df1["Combination"] = df1["Date"] + df1["Color"]`

Comment: it gave me the following error, TypeError: incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation

Comment: could you check and tell me what dtypes your columns are? you could do this by `df1.dtypes`

Comment: level_0                                 int64
index                                   int64
Report Number                          int64
Occurred_Date                  datetime64[ns]
Occurred Time                          int64
Reported Date                  datetime64[ns]
Reported Time                           int64
Crime Subcategory                  object
Primary Offense Description        object
Precinct                        object
Sector                                object
Beat                                   object
Neighborhood                    object
dtype: object

Comment: ok, I see now. It's not possible because you can't concatenate 'datetime64[ns]' and string. To solve this you have to change dtype of column 'Occurred Date' from 'datetime64[ns]' to string by following command: `df['Occurred Date'] = df['Occurred Date'].astype('str')`. After that you should have to combine them as discussed above.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please explain to me the code you wrote that converted the date to string? and how can i convert it back for instance can i change the .astype('str') to .astype('date') or ('datetime')?

Comment: That line of code do exactly that, changes data type from one format to another, as in this case from datetime to str. You could easily use it in the reverse way from str to datetime when sting is in format (i.e. 29-05-2018) or smth like this, that could be converted to datetime. I hope that explanation works for you.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.